# How to make a canvas component fully opaque in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, canvas

I have a canvas component that I create and add as a child of a parent canvas component.  I set the opaqueBackground property for the child component which makes it opaque over the parent component.  However, when I add two child components, they are not opaque over each other.  How do I set it up so that one child component completely covers up the other child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought:

1) Are you using cacheAsBitmap?  [opaqueBackground](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground) is designed for use with cacheAsBitmap in order to improve rendering.  If you just want to make something transparent, would [alpha](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#alpha) work better for you?

Second thought:

2) Styles are inherited, but properties generally aren't.  If you want to pass the property value onto one of a component's children, override the property set method to set a flag and invalidateProperties().  Then use commitProperties() to set your children.

Third thought:

3) It sounds like you may want only one child active at once.  Perhaps you want to look into using the [visible](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#visible) property or a [ViewStack](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_3.html) or [states](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=using_states_3.html)?

Comment: I ended up just working with the visible property for the children.  However, I'm still curious how I would make one child opaque over (completely cover up) another child that it overlaps.  There must be some property that I am missing that can do this.